# flat list of values in nested serializers

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

Say I have serializers as below.

```
class AbcSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Abc
        fields = ('a',) # there could be other fields too in model.


class XyzSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    a = AbcSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Xyz
        fields = '__all__'
```

this gives me list of dictionaries like

```
[{a: 1}, {a: 2}]
```

is there any parameter like `flat=True`, which would give me a flat list like

```
[1, 2]
```

Comment: use `serializers.SerializerMethodField` to get desired output. can you show the models for answering the question

Comment: @AneeshRS yes, that could be one of the approaches.

Comment: Can you share the model code

Comment: What's up with the models?

Answer (score 3):

```
class XyzSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

     a = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
     class Meta:
         model = Xyz
         fields = '__all__'  
     def get_a(self, obj):
         return [a.a for a in obj.a.all()]
```